# Find the conditional expectation $E[X_2|F_1]$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

$X_n$ is a sequence of random variables.

Let $X_0 = 4$, $X_n=2X_{n-1}$ with prob $= 3/4$ or $X_n=0.5X_{n-1}$ with prob $= 1/4$. $F_i$ is a filtration of the sigma field. $F_0 = \{$null,$\omega\}$, $F_1= \sigma (X_1)$, $F_2 = \sigma(X_1,X_2)$. Find the conditional expectation $E[X_2|F_1]$.

This is a question on a test I had today, and I think I did it wrong. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you write, and why do you think it was wrong?

Comment: well I wrote E[X2|F1] = X2 , and I thought X2 is F1 measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let X0 = 4, Xn=2*X(n-1) with prob = 3/4 or Xn=0.5*X(n-1) with prob = 1/4.

This might mean that $X_0=4$ and that, for every $n\geqslant1$, $X_n=Y_nX_{n-1}$ where $P[Y_n=2]=\frac34$, $P[Y_n=\frac12]=\frac14$ and $Y_n$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{n-1}=\sigma(X_k;0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1)$. Or not.

If it does, the well-known motto "integrate what is independent and take out what is measurable" yields $E[Y_nX_{n-1}\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}]=E[Y_n]\,X_{n-1}$, that is, $E[X_n\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}]=\frac{13}8\,X_{n-1}$.

Re your answer to the test, note that $E[X_2\mid\mathcal F_1]=X_2$ if and only if $X_2$ is $\mathcal F_1$-measurable.

**Edit (about "Or not" above):** Here is an example where $X_1=2X_0$ with probability $\frac34$, $X_1=\frac12X_0$ with probability $\frac14$, $X_2=2X_1$ with probability $\frac34$, $X_2=\frac12X_1$ with probability $\frac14$, and yet $E[X_2\mid\mathcal F_1]\ne\frac{13}8\,X_1$.

To this end, assume that $X_1=Y_1X_0$ as above, and that $X_2=Y_1X_1$. Then $E[X_2\mid\mathcal F_1]=\frac14X_1^2$ and $\frac14X_1^2\ne\frac{13}8\,X_1$ with full probability since $X_1$ is almost surely $8$ or $2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out myself earlier today with a similar result by a different methods. I used the definition of conditional expectation. However your method is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $\mathbb{E}[X_2 | X_1]$ first.  Recall that $\mathbb{E}[X|B] = \sum_{\omega \in B} X(\omega) P(\omega | B)$.

$\mathbb{E}[X_2 | X_1] = 2 X_1 P( X_2 = 2 X_1 | X_1) + 0.5 X_1 P( X_2 = 0.5 X_1 | X_1)
  = 2 X_1 \bullet \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2} X_1 \bullet \frac{1}{4} = \frac{13}{8} X_1 \, .$

Since $\mathcal{F_1} = \sigma(X_1)$, $\mathbb{E}[X_2 | \mathcal{F}_1] = \mathbb{E}[X_2 | X_1] = \frac{13}{8} X_1 \, .$

Comment: "Since X1 is F1-measurable, E[X2|F1]=E[E[X2|X1]|F1]" The argument is wrong. The last identity requires the *reversed* inclusion of the sigma-algebras, that is, it would hold if F1 was a sub-sigma-algebra of sigma(X1).

Comment: Did: let me think about the argument some more, but do you agree that $\mathbb{E}[X_2 | \mathcal{F}_1] = \mathbb{E}[X_2 | X_1] = \frac{13}{8} X_1$?

Comment: In the present case, since F1=sigma(X1), yes.

Comment: Did: You are right about the problem with my original argument. I got rid of it in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the new version raises a different problem: conditional expectations are not defined pointwise except in the discrete case. Here the quantities $E[X_2\mid X_1=x_1]$ are not well defined.

Comment: Did: is the original problem discrete? The $n$ in $X_n$ are integers.

Comment: Did: referring to the original problem, you are saying that we cannot say what $\mathbb{E}[X_2 | X_1 = 1]$ is because the quantity is not well defined?  I disagree.  Given that $X_1 = 1$, $X_2$ is either 2 (with probability 3/4) or 0.5.

Comment: Did: using my example above, I can still compute what $\mathbb{E}[X_2 | X_1 = 1]$ is, which evaluates to 13/8.

Comment: "The n in Xn are integers" Why should we care? But it is true that the random variables Xn are discrete in the setting of this exercise hence one can indeed consider E[X2|X1=x1], I missed this fact in my previous comment, sorry. But... it is a bad idea, as the other post where you tried to use the method, shows.

Comment: Did: I was trying to figure out what you meant by "except in the discrete case".

Comment: Did: my solution got around the issue you wrote about in yours that "$Y_n$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{n−1}$...Or not."

Comment: No. You just used the hypothesis without noticing it.

Comment: ... And the exact step where you used this hypothesis is when you wrote that $P[X_2=2X_1\mid X_1]=\frac34$. There is no way to assert this from what is written in the question.

Comment: Did: the question says "$X_n=2*X_{n-1}$ with prob = $3/4$".  So given $X_1$, the probability of $X_2 = 2 X_1$ is $3/4$.

Comment: No. You added "given $X_1$", which makes all the difference.